# How to design schema relation in SQL to mongoDB?

Tags: database-design, mongodb, schema

I still confuse after read mongoDB The Definitive Guide and this link http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design
is there standard for mongodb to design the schema database. I have the schema in MySQL database like this below 
[image: SQL Database design]

my database above is fixed & just for DDL. Please help me show the step to design schema relation above to mongoDB. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to think of Mongo is a document storage system.  From quickly looking at your schema....  All of that should go into a document per named thing in your main table.

However, it depends a lot on how you use it.

But, just to be clear,  there is not a straight conversion between a relational model and a document model.

Comment: whether I embed all table to the main table? like in this link below
[http://pastebin.com/53tjak6L](http://pastebin.com/53tjak6L)
when we have to make more than one collection?

Comment: what's the nature of your application and how will you be querying the data? as keith said, your schema design depends on how you're going to be using the data.

Comment: DDL?  as in how you structure data in NoSQL?  The point being made is that the way you structure and partition data in NoSQL depends a lot on how you are going to use that data.  Or trying to draw parallels with SQL.  They way you structure data in NoSQL is related to the queries you'd do in SQL,  eg,  a Document is a prejoined set of tables. More importantly it represents the most common and useful join of data.  You then need to think carefully about queries across documents and how you will handle that.  Ideally you create a document that has all the data for all the types of queries.

Comment: That's not always possible, or sensible.  But its all about thinking about how you are going to use the data for the application.